# Is it true in general that $\int_{|X| \leq \epsilon} |X|^r \, d\mathbb{P} \leq \epsilon^r$?

Tags: probability, integration, measure-theory

If I have that $X$ is a random variable, for $\epsilon > 0$, and $r \geq 1$, is it true that:

$$\int_{|X| \leq \epsilon} |X|^r \, d\mathbb{P} \leq \epsilon^r.$$?

If so, is there a reason why? Here, I have that $\mathbb{P}$ is the probability measure. I have tried to see it intuitively in terms of drawing a graph, but I don't see how a single evaluated point is less than an integral, which incorporates areas. Any hints would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I mean to say $r \geq 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For arbitrary $r>0$, yes.

For any $x$ such that $\lvert x\rvert \leq \varepsilon$, you have $\lvert x\rvert^r \leq \varepsilon^r$ since $t\mapsto t^r$ is increasing on $[0,\infty)$, and then
$$
\int_{\Omega} \mathbb{1}_{\{\lvert X\rvert \leq \varepsilon\}} \lvert X\rvert^r d\mathbb{P} \leq 
\int_{\Omega} \mathbb{1}_{\{\lvert X\rvert \leq \varepsilon\}} \varepsilon^r d\mathbb{P} \leq  
\varepsilon^r  \int_{\Omega} d\mathbb{P} = \varepsilon^r \cdot 1 = \varepsilon^r 
$$

Comment: Thank you! Is there perhaps a way to see his graphically or in terms of a picture?

Comment: Not quite sure about this, but essentially you are taking an expectation of $\lvert X\rvert^r$ in a region where $\lvert X\rvert^r \leq \varepsilon^r$: in other terms, you are averaging values that are all at most $\varepsilon^r$. The average will be at most $\varepsilon^r$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = |x|^r$ for $|x| \le \epsilon$, $0$ otherwise.  Then your integral is $\mathbb E[f(X)]$.  But $f(X) \le \epsilon^r$ always, so $\mathbb E[f(X)] \le \epsilon^r$.